# Calling a function in useEffect which upon completion calls another function but can't stop rerendering even with use call back

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I am calling a function in useEffect which I only want to run once. Upon completion this function calls another function which again should only run once. I originally had it setup with no problem but then got warnings about dependencies so I did some research and added a useCallback but that made the useCallback ask for dependencies which I added now it's back to re rendering multiple times. I know I could either use a class component or redux but I was hoping there is a solution this way since I am not really doing much with the data that is coming back.

```
function SuccessScreen() {


const navigate = useNavigate()
const dispatch = useDispatch()

let search = window.location.search
let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(search)
let sessionId = urlParams.get('session_id')
const userInfo = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin.userInfo)
const order = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Order"))
const [success, setSuccess] = useState("")
const [name, setName] = useState("")
const [orderNumber, setOrderNumber] = useState()

const saveOrder = useCallback(async () => {
    let temp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo'));

    const config = { headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + temp.token || "" } }
    const res = await axios.post("/api/v1/orders", { order }, config)
    console.log(res)
    if (res.data.status === 401) {
        alert("your session timed out please login")
        dispatch(logout())
    } else if (res.status === 200) {
        setSuccess(" your order was placed and your order number is ")
        setName(res.data.firstName + " " + res.data.lastName)
        setOrderNumber(res.data._id)
        window.localStorage.removeItem('Order');
    } else {
        setSuccess("There was a problem, Your order may have went through please call the store to verify")
    }
}, [dispatch, order])


console.log("order", order)
const getStripeOrder = useCallback(() => {

    if (userInfo === null) {
        navigate("/login")
    }
    else if (sessionId !== null && order !== null) {
        axios.post("/api/v1/checkout/order/success", { sessionId })
            .then((res) => {

                if (res.data.email === userInfo.doc.email) {
                    saveOrder()
                }

            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }
}, [navigate, order, saveOrder, sessionId, userInfo])




useEffect(() => {


    getStripeOrder()

}, [getStripeOrder])

return (
    <div>
        <div>
            <Navigation />
        </div>
        <div className='orderplaced'>
            <OrderPlaced message={success} name={name} orderNumber={orderNumber} />
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can supress the warnings for dependencies by adding this comment above the dependency array.

//eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

This will make the linter to stop searching for dependencies and will trigger your effect only once. Before doing this, try to remove the dependency array completely and check if the double render still occurs. If so, add the comment that I showed above like so:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getStripeOrder()
  }, 
  //eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  [])
```

If you do this you don't need useCallback(). useCallback() is useful when you want to cache a certain function and pass a new instance of it down to another component only if a change in the dependencies occur or if you want to cache that function within a component.